# Powershell API Post Variable to Ducksboard

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

Trying to use the following Powershell script which I've taken from Github to push data into a Ducksboard dashboard. The function works excellently however I need to feed in a variable as part of the data. Of the two calls to the function included below the function which pushes in the actual value 44 works fine, however if I substitute it for my variable $qtybord the function falls over. I've tried a number of options to overcome the var being within the single quotes but cannot get it to work - can anyone help me?

```
# Squirt data to Duscksboard
    function Execute-DucksboardApi
    {
      param(
        [string] $url = $null,
        [string] $data = $null,
        [string] $apikey = $null,
        [string] $contentType = "application/json",
        [string] $codePageName = "UTF-8",
        [string] $userAgent = $null
      );

      if ($url -and $data -and $apikey)
      {
        [System.Net.WebRequest]$webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url);
        $webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = $false;
        [System.Net.NetworkCredential]$credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($apikey, 'ignored');
        $webRequest.Credentials = $credentials.GetCredential($url, 'Basic');
        $webRequest.PreAuthenticate = $true;
        $webRequest.ContentType = $contentType;
        $webRequest.Method = "POST";
        if ( $userAgent )
        {
          $webRequest.UserAgent = $userAgent;
        }

        $enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($codePageName);
        [byte[]]$bytes = $enc.GetBytes($data);
        $webRequest.ContentLength = $bytes.Length;
        [System.IO.Stream]$reqStream = $webRequest.GetRequestStream();
        $reqStream.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length);
        $reqStream.Flush();

        $resp = $webRequest.GetResponse();
        $rs = $resp.GetResponseStream();
        [System.IO.StreamReader]$sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -argumentList $rs;
        $sr.ReadToEnd();
      }
    }

    $qtybord = 44

    Execute-DucksboardApi -url 'https://push.ducksboard.com/v/123752/' -data '{"value": $qtybord}' -apikey 'tu2j3d3epqytWZD1haHnjJSJ1NqBrmvPe5SONc0VYge4BbIPi0'

Execute-DucksboardApi -url 'https://push.ducksboard.com/v/123752/' -data '{"value": 44}' -apikey 'tu2j3d3epqytWZD1haHnjJSJ1NqBrmvPe5SONc0VYge4BbIPi0'
```

*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
-data "{`"value`": $qtybord}"
```

or

```
-data "{""value"": $qtybord}"
```

in single quote variable aren't expanded, in double quote you need to escape the double quote inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

So make the -data parameter take $data instead and make $data = '{"value": ' + $qtyboard + '}' or just wrap that whole thing in parens after -data.

Also, if you're on PowerShell v3 you can play with something like this:

```
$data = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
   value = $qtyboard
} | ConvertTo-JSON
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the response however $data = '{"value": ' + $qtybord + '}' still fails with errors.